# How the following SQL query is working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-management

How is the given query correct as it is using T1 inside the with clause and T1 is declared after the clause within WITH is completed.

```
WITH T1(Emp,Manager,Salary) AS 
( 
SELECT tt2.[Emp],tt2.[Manager],tt2.[Salary] 
FROM [YourTable] AS tt1 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [YourTable] AS tt2 ON tt1.[Emp]=tt2.[Manager] 
WHERE tt1.[Emp] is NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT r.[Emp],T1.[Manager],r.[Salary] 
FROM [YourTable] AS r 
INNER JOIN T1 ON r.[Manager]=T1.[Emp] 
) 
SELECT [Manager],SUM([Salary]) AS Salary 
FROM T1 
GROUP BY [Manager] 
ORDER BY SUM([Salary]) DESC
```

Above query is answer to following question -

I have table with columns (Employee, Manager, Salary). Need to calculate aggregate salary for all employees corresponding to top-level managers in one SQL. For example

```
Input table is : 
Emp Manager Salary 
A   T   10 
B   A   11 
C   F   13 
D   B   5
```

Result should be :

```
Top-Lvl Manager Salary(agg) 
T   26 
F   13
```

Manager-Employee layering can go multiple levels.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: This query has been built using CTE(Comman Table Expression). For more info on this, please go through this link-https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275645/CTE-In-SQL-Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a recursive query. The part before `UNION ALL` gets the base records. The part after it recursively gets more rows attatched to the former.

The first part is confusingly written. It is an anti-join pattern inplemented even with a right outer join which many consider hard to read. It merely means this:

```
select emp, manager, salary 
from yourtable
where manager not in (select emp from yourtable);
```

So you get all employees that have no manager (i.e. the super managers).

With the part after `UNION ALL` you get their subordinates and the subordinates of these etc. A hierarchical query.

At last in

```
SELECT [Manager],SUM([Salary]) AS Salary 
FROM T1 
GROUP BY [Manager] 
ORDER BY SUM([Salary]) DESC
```

you use those rows to get a cumulated salary per manager.

You can read up on recursive queries in SQL Server here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx.

Answer (score 2):

> **EDIT - Less over-kill**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Emp varchar(25),Manager varchar(25),Salary int)
Insert into @YourTable values 
('A','T',10),
('B','A',11), 
('C','F',13),
('D','B',5) 

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by Emp) as varchar(500))
            ,Emp=Manager
            ,Manager=cast(null as varchar(25))
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Salary = 0
      From  @YourTable 
      Where Manager Not In (Select Distinct Emp From @YourTable)
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.Emp)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.Emp
            ,r.Manager
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.Salary
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.Manager = p.Emp)
Select TopLvl = A.Emp
      ,Salary = sum(B.Salary)
 from cteP A
 Join cteP B on (B.Seq Like A.Seq+'%')
 Where A.Lvl=1
 Group By A.Emp
```

Returns

```
TopLvl  Salary
F       13
T       26
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `with` `T1` references to `INNER JOIN T1 ON r.[Manager]=T1.[Emp]` which is probably table in your DB. Outside `with` `T1` references to result of `with` statement.

Comment: I don't think it is that way. There is no other table named T1. It is using T1 because it need to do it recursively to single layering for Manager-Employee multi level layering.

Comment: If you're sure that there is no T1 table nor synonym it means Thorsten's answer is what works here.